# How could I define the threads count when using tempus-fugit and junit?

Tags: java, concurrency, junit, webdriver

I am using [tempus-fugit](http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/) in order to execute junit tests in parallel. My test classes contain multiple WebDriver junit tests (>20) and each test lasts more than 20-40 secs.

**This is the problem:**

When my tests are triggered simultaneously, more than 20 firefox sessions are created and our system doesn't have the resources to handle that!

**This is what I would like to achieve:**

I would like to limit somehow the threads count when using fugit's ConcurrentTestRunner.class runner so that only 3-4 tests running in parallel each time. I know that I could achieve that by moving from JUnit to TestNG but this is not an option for many reasons!

**This is how my Test class looks:**

```
import com.google.code.tempusfugit.concurrency.ConcurrentTestRunner;

@RunWith(ConcurrentTestRunner.class)
public class TestClass{
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        // Do something with Selenium WebDriver
    }

    // ...
    // More Tests
    // ...

    @Test
    public void test20(){
        // Do something with Selenium WebDriver
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Unfortunately, the documentation of the tempus-fugit library does not say anything about how somebody can limit the threads count but I'm guessing it is feasible!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the `@Concurrent` with `ConcurrentTestRunner` to limit the number of threads.

It's available on Github and I've pushed a snapshot release (1.2 #3) to [Sonatype](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/code/tempus-fugit/tempus-fugit/1.2-SNAPSHOT/).

Take a look [at the commit on Github](https://github.com/tobyweston/tempus-fugit/commit/08a35ff2273e6495cfc0cf5ea974f5a587e3d93a) for details.

Use it something like

```
@RunWith(ConcurrentTestRunner.class)
@Concurrent(count = 5)
public class ConcurrentTestRunnerTest {

    private static final Set<String> threads = synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Caveat:** I bent this in so your mileage may vary, let me know how you get on!

Comment: Toby it seems to work perfectly. Please let me thank you for your direct and helpful response. My reputation does not allow me to vote up unfortunately.